# How to determine which part of a WHERE clause caused a row not to be found?

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, derby, resultset

I know that if the SQL String statement is satisfied, next() will continue to check each row. Otherwise, false if it can't satisfy the SQL Select Statement. ( I hope i didn't miss anything)

If my statement is

```
ResultSet myRs1 = null;
            String SQL1 = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME = ? AND PASSWORD = ? AND USERTYPE = ?";
```

If username value on textfield matches username in the row BUT password  doesn't match in the same column, what method should I use?
Also, if rowCounter returns false and counts false as 0, how do I compare the password? I'm thinking of getters

I want to do something like

```
if((usernameInTextField found in current row) BUT (passwordInTextField doesn't match password in current row))
Print message "Password Incorrect"
```

Please be patient with me as I'm new to JDBC.

Here's my code:

```
ResultSet myRs1 = null;
            String SQL1 = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE USERNAME = ? AND PASSWORD = ? AND USERTYPE = ?";


        try {
          myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,username,password);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully Connected To Database");

            PreparedStatement myPrepStmt = myConnection.prepareStatement(SQL1);
                myPrepStmt.setString(1,userNameEntered); //assigns a string value to the first ?
                myPrepStmt.setString(2,passwordEntered); //assigns a string value to the second ?
                myPrepStmt.setString(3,userTypeEntered);
            myRs1 = myPrepStmt.executeQuery(); // executes the select query and stores it to myRs

            int rowCounter = 0;
            while(myRs1.next()) //as long as query is satisfied, next() will return true
            {
                rowCounter++; 
            }

            if(rowCounter == 0) 
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Username, Password or Usertype maybe incorrect");
            }
            else if(rowCounter > 1) //if there are duplications 
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User details found but has more 1 one entry" +
                        "\nFound: " + rowCounter + " rows" );
            }
            else if(rowCounter == 1){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Found " + rowCounter + " record");
            }


        } //end of try
        catch (SQLException e) {
}
```

My code works using rowCounter but can't specify which is incorrect(username/password/usertype).

Thanks.

Comment: Well, if your SQL statement does not return any row because it doesn't match anything, how would you compare anything to nothing? You could create a second select to check, if the username exists at all.

Comment: It's actually common practice to only tell the user "User name or password invalid", so you could just ignore the fact that a correct username was passed in.

Comment: If you really want to know whether the username matched, but the password did not, you could issue a **separate** SELECT statement which only contained `where USERNAME = ? and USERTYPE=?`. Then if that statement returns a row, but the query with the password does not, you've identified that it was the password column that didn't match.

Comment: Your query already points to a security flaw: the password should be salted and hashed, and not stored plaintext. Normally you query the user, and the hash the password give with the same salt and compared against the stored password hash.